# Drawing Charts in .NET

Tags: .net, charts, graph-drawing

I have some input data (string-double) (server application). I need to draw a chart and **save it as a picture**.

What tools can I use?

PS.

I have some server side code that should generate this chart from some data. Can I have the image WITHOUT displaying the chart to the user (in a Web or Win Form)?

Comment: Maybe the Microsoft Chart Control? http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart